# How to query using auto generated id and get know if it is an edge id or vertex id

Tags: postgresql, graph-databases, apache-age

Hot to query using the auto generated id in the apache age graph database.

I want to get to know if it is edge id or a vertex id.

For example i have an id `844424930131970`. I know its somewhere within graph. But I don't know if its id for a vertex or an id for edge

Comment: Please edit and clarify your question. Are you talking about using the graph oid to find out if something is an edge or a vertex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would sort of depend on what you're trying to `MATCH` on to determine if it is a vertex or an edge.  I don't think it is possible to match on an abstract object in the graph.

For a vertex:

```
postgresDB=# SELECT * FROM cypher('airroutes', $$
MATCH (n)
WHERE id(n) = 844424930131969
RETURN n $$)
AS (n agtype);
                                                                                                                                                                        n     
                                                                                                                                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "airport", "properties": {"id": "1", "lat": "33.63669968", "lon": "-84.42810059", "city": "Atlanta", "code": "ATL", "desc": "Hartsfield - Ja
ckson Atlanta International Airport", "elev": "1026", "icao": "KATL", "__id__": 1, "region": "US-GA", "country": "US", "longest": "12390", "runways": "5"}}::vertex
```

For an edge:

```
postgresDB=# SELECT * FROM cypher('airroutes', $$
MATCH ()-[e]-() 
WHERE id(e) = 1688849860263937
RETURN e $$)
AS (n agtype);
                                                                                             n                                                                                
             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------
 {"id": 1688849860263937, "label": "route", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "properties": {"dist": "809", "route_id": "3749", "end_vertex_type": "airp
ort"}}::edge
 {"id": 1688849860263937, "label": "route", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "properties": {"dist": "809", "route_id": "3749", "end_vertex_type": "airp
ort"}}::edge
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out the particular ID that corresponds to any edge or vertex, you can examine the data model by taking a look at the structure of the graph and understand the type of edges and vertices that the edges are represented using.

You can also look at the ID ranges to to check for a specific vertex of edge that may be part of a particular range.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine whether the ID is edge id or vertex one then you can use the following clauses:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = 844424930131970
RETURN
  CASE
    WHEN n:VertexType THEN 'Vertex'
    WHEN n:EdgeType THEN 'Edge'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
  END AS Type;
```

You just need to replace the `VertexType` and `EdgeType` with your actual labels.

Comment: This query doesn't make any sense. It always matches vertices.